# Getting error while trying to install vuestorefront using npm

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vue-storefront

I am getting the below error while trying to install vuestorefront using npm on windows. Any idea how to fix it ?

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
core/scripts/server.ts:1:38 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@vue-storefront/core/server/hooks' or 
its corresponding type declarations.

1 import { serverHooksExecutors } from '@vue-storefront/core/server/hooks'
                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

at createTSError (D:\vueRepo\vue-storefront\vue-storefront\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:434:12)
at reportTSError (D:\vueRepo\vue-storefront\vue-storefront\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:438:19)
at getOutput (D:\vueRepo\vue-storefront\vue-storefront\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:578:36)
at Object.compile (D:\vueRepo\vue-storefront\vue-storefront\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:775:32)
at Module.m._compile (D:\vueRepo\vue-storefront\vue-storefront\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:858:43)
at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1164:10)
at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (D:\vueRepo\vue-storefront\vue-storefront\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:861:12)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:993:32)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:892:14)
```

Answer (score 1):

[vue-storefront](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront) works better with yarn. Try to update your yarn, then `yarn install` and `yarn dev`. More informations can be found [here](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront/issues/2128).